# What is step by step process for add products to magento guest cart using Rest apis?

Tags: rest, cart, magento2

I am trying like this,

Step 1: Post(empty) baseurl/rest/V1/guest-carts

get: guest customerid =02ccea0d67a4be667fa6ebf7905tia21

Step 2: I want add items to cart,so am using this api, POST /V1/guest-carts/{cartId}/items

```
Post: {
"cartItem": {
"itemId": 2,
"sku": "RJ0111",
"qty": 1,
"name": "Normal Kit",
"quoteId": "02ccea0d67a4be667fa6ebf7905tia21",
}
```

baseurl/rest/V1/guest-carts/02ccea0d67a4be667fa6ebf7905tia21/items

it gives response as 400 Bad Request,how can i get this and please tell me process step by step.

and what is "quoteId" here,

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the documentation and error messages in Magento are not very clear on things like this.

http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#/

You are correct in that step 1 is to get the cart id using:

```
[POST] {base URL}/rest/V1/guest-carts
```

Step 2 is to add the product to cart, using the cart id returned from step 1:

```
[POST] {base URL}/rest/V1/guest-carts/{cartId}/items
```

However, the format of your data needs to be like this:

```
        {
            "cart_item": {
                "quote_id": cartId,
                "sku": itemSku,
                "qty": quantity
            }
        }
```

In Magento 2, a quote is the backend name for what we see as a cart in the frontend and so quoteId and cartId are the same.